# Executing Batch file from java and open the cmd of running batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, exec

I was trying to execute the batch file from java. My requirement is when the java execute the batch file, the command window should open. currently nothing happen.

My code is:

```
String[] batchArg = {"cmd", "/k", "cd /d C:\\<path to batch file> & <batchfilename>.bat",a[1],arr[2]};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batchArg);
```

also try this:

```
 String[] batchArg = {"cmd","C:\\<path to batch file> & <batchfilename>.bat",a[1],arr[2]};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batchArg);
```

I have tried /C as well

if i run the batch file from start menu with this command or by double click it is executing correctly.

please let me know,

thanks in advance

Comment: What is `a`? What is `arr`? What are the contents of your batch file? Is it possible that your batch file is so simple that it runs very fast and you miss it?

Comment: a is the argument i am passing

Answer (score 2):

Batch files alone can't be executed. They need an application to run them. In your case, that application is `cmd.exe`. Windows Explorer takes care of this when you run a batch by clicking on it. Java doesn't have this luxury.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start HelloWorld.bat"); // *
```

Another similar command that anyone reading this would be familiar with is:

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

Notice how you had to specify which application you wanted to use to run this file? Typing the file name, `HelloWorld.java`, all by itself would not accomplish much.

<sub>*The `/c` switch puts the output in a new window which terminates when the batch file has completed.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a waitFor() to your code.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C e:/Users/Bryan/touchafile.bat");
p.waitFor();
```

Also you might find looking at the output of the process useful.

```
InputStream error = p.getErrorStream();
InputStream output = p.getInputStream();
System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(error));
System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(output));
```